# Curly hair animated

Tags: physics, hair

So, looking on this research paper ( http://graphics.pixar.com/library/CurlyHairB/paper.pdf ) I wasn't able to recreate even the starting point on the trouble that Pixar had simulating hair. In blender hair is a straight strand, if you want to have a curly hair you have to use children. And it only curls it along the straight strand (the one who is simulated), so it doesn't have compression between the loops (natural of curly hair).

I added a gif of a single strand with hair dynamics and with one children curled (on the left) and a faked one with a not physically real animation of the real curl hair while walking.

[image: Curly Hair]

As you could see, the hair simulation doesn't compress itself (because real straight hair doesn't compress) so the problem isn't in the simulation, is in the way you curl the hair. In blender (as far as I know, that isn't too much) you create a straight strand of hair that is simulated, and then you create a child (curled in this case) around the straight strand. So the loops of hair that you create with childrens aren't simulated properly.

You can curl the hair manually in the particle edit mode, but I'm looking for a method that could work with many hair strands.

Is a way to correctly curl the hair that I missed (probably)?? An addon?? Should I ask for it on the blender development site??

Comment: Please make your writing clearer.  I find the writing in you question to be confusing.  Others may find it clear.  There appears to be many words missing.  I believe some of your long sentences can be made into two sentences.  Probably the best person to make your question clearer is you.  Please read your question carefully and make improvements.

Comment: Changed, is understandable now? Sorry about the misspelled words and wrong grammar, but English isn't my first language.

Comment: Have you used [particle mode] on the hair ? [Yes, No]  This would demonstrate hair can be combed in a wavy/curly fashion.  Please use particle mode to style your hair a little.

Comment: This may be related to advanced hair management. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5pxZtmlqtvc I have not seen the video recently yet I remember the provider managing hair with a curve ... not necessarily physics.  I consider this video to be intermediate to advanced.  You must judge if it is relevant.

Comment: atomicbezierslinger , your answer works, thanks, but if I have a head, it is almost impossible to edit every strand, gonna update the question. Also, I think your answer would have been better on as an answer than a comment because is very useful.

Comment: The point is to use particle edit mode and probably children together.